# How to use JLex.CAlloc.class

Tags: java

I downloaded and imported xalan-2.5.0.jar to my netbeans project in order to use the CAlloc.class function. But i cant figure out how to use the CAlloc function. 
i imported the package by doing this,

```
import JLex.*;
```

i wanted to import specifically the calloc class but i get error when i tried this

```
import JLex.CAlloc;
```

the error says "CAlloc is not public in JLex; cannot be accessed from outside package" , i opened and checked the CAlloc.class and it not public but i cant edit it, may be if there is a way to edit the class ???

Comment: by learning basic Java OOP and maybe checking the classes documentation

Comment: or if someone can change this C code to java                                                          
              iq_buff = calloc(2*iq_buff_size, 1)